# What method can I use instead of __file__ in python?

Tags: python, cython

I convert my python code to c by cython and after that compile .c file and use .so in my project. 
My problem:
I use `__file__` in my python code and in while compile by gcc, it doesn't get error. but when I run program and import .so in other python files, appear an error from `__file__` line.

How can solve this problem? Is there any method to replace with `__file__`?

Comment: What do you use it for?

Comment: `__file__` does now work on recent versions of Cython (>0.27) when run on Python 3.5+.

Comment: `__file__` gives me "built-in" instead of the filename in Cython >0.29 on Python 3.7.0

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try to add this at the beginning of your file:

```
import inspect
import sys
if not hasattr(sys.modules[__name__], '__file__'):
    __file__ = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())
```

Comment: That only works for Python code stack frames, **not** for C extensions.

Comment: If you only need to get a package root path in Cython module, but `__file__` is not defined due to the Python bug http://bugs.python.org/issue13429, then you can use a simple trick by referencing `__init__.py`: `def get_package_root(): from . import __file__ as initpy_file_path; return os.path.dirname(initpy_file_path)`

Comment: @MartijnPieters what is your suggestion for C extensions?

Comment: This answer didn't work correctly for me, it was returning cwd, while Vlad Frolov answer did the job!

Answer (score 0):

Not too sure how you will make it python compatible but gcc `#define`s `__FILE__` for the name of the file that the code is in.

Answer (score 0):

why not use `sys.argv[0]` ?

This works even when it's compiled into a cython executable.

Comment: But doesn't work in any other case. You're often using `__file__` to work out where a module is installed